# How to convert Jupyter/IPython notebooks to LaTex?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter, pdflatex

How can I export Jupyter notebooks to LaTeX? I can convert to PDF through LaTeX using the inbuilt menus but I'm unsure how to step in at the intermediate step and extract the actual LaTeX file.

Comment: `jupyter nbconvert` from commandline should do.  `--to latex` is the flag you may want to use.

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to add that as an answer for me to accept?

Comment: feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to do this from the command line rather than the web interface with the following command:

`jupyter nbconvert /path/to/mynotebook.ipynb --to latex`

Comment: This answer is old. I am using File | Download As... | Latex. Pandoc must be installed.

Comment: docs: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-latex

Comment: We can even go to "File" -> "Save and Export Notebook As..." -> "LaTeX" in Jupyter Lab. Assuming that TeXlive and Pandoc have been installed on your system. However, I do prefer this solution! It is convenient when we use VSCode :D

Answer (score 4):

Anaconda Navigator provides **JupyterLab**. Use this to open jupyter notebook.

Under File menu you can find an item "Export Notebook As...".

This provides format such as Asciidoc, HTML, latex, pdf, Markdown, etc.
You can choose your desired format.

Comment: +1 Just note that you don't need to use Anaconda Navigator for this; any way of installing JupyterLab should work.  Just be sure to install `pandoc` as well.